# Limit User Abilities During RODBC Connection

Tags: r, rodbc

We have a database that we are connecting to via RODBC, the accounts have been given read only access on the database side, however if we log in via R we are able to read/write/execute. I have been using the read only command within the connection command as follows:

`odbcConnect(dsn = "DSN",uid="un",pwd="pass",readOnly=T)`

I've noticed that, while users cannot write to tables or write to new tables, they can create new tables. I would like to ensure that users are unable to modify the database to open this to a broader user group. Has anyone found a sure fire way to limit user access from the R side?

Comment: The R side is the wrong side to control DB permissions. It sounds like your accounts have been misconfigured. I would suggest asking a question under your database's tag about how to correctly configure user accounts for read only access.

Comment: As a sidenote, `odbcConnect` passes `...` along to `odbcDriverConnect`. There is no argument `readOnly` for either of those functions. Via partial matching, you are setting `readOnlyOptimize = T`, which means you are optimizing your connection for read operations, not restricting it. You may have been confused because the same documentation page includes the functions for connecting to Excel files, and `odbcConnectExcel` and `odbcConnectExcel2007` do have `readOnly` arguments. [Here's a documentation link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RODBC/versions/1.3-15/topics/odbcConnect).

Comment: Aha, thank you @Gregor, I was misinterpreting that document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments made by Gregor, the issue is not R side it is database side. The system that was being dealt with was performing security checks on a front end application rather than at the ODBC handshake. As such, R had no way of enforcing rules that were not enforced server side.